# How to seperate a consumer from consumer group without losing offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I have a logstash kafka consumer group subscribing nearly 20topics which isn't performing well for a particular high priority kafka topic to process, so I've decided to remove one topic out of the consumer group and launch a separate consumer group for high priority topics, but unfortunately with that i'm losing the offset that was there in old consumer group.

Is there anyway I can start the new logstash consumer group with the initial offset from last consumer group?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use kafka scripts to set offset for new group.

Sample scenario:

1. Stop application.
2. Check current offset for group. You can use following command. The output will contains information about current offset, log end offset, lag, etc for each topic.

   `./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group groupId --describe`
3. Set offset for new group id, that will be used by new application (suppose the offset for topic you would like to *switch* is `10001`)

   `./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group newGroupId --to-offset 10001 --topic topicName --reset-offsets --execute`
4. Remove `topicName` from topics list for old application.
5. Set up new logstash configuration with `newGroupId` group id.
6. Start *old* and *new* logstash applications.